# feed systemctl into python websocket - systemctl missing new information

Tags: python, websocket, subprocess, popen, systemctl

I am trying to pipe a dameon service's status into a websocket. It works but it only shows the information in the logs at the time of running the code. It doesn't wait and show me new information like when I run other processes.

I am using `flask-sock` for the websocket and I am using `subprocess.popen` to pipe the information into the websocket.

```py
@sock.route('/eprotectview')
def eprotectview(ws):
    data = ws.receive()
    with subprocess.Popen(['systemctl status eprotection'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, bufsize=1,
                          universal_newlines=True) as process:
        for line in process.stdout:
            line = line.rstrip()
            print(line)
            try:
                ws.send(line + "\n")
            except:
                pass
```

It works but it doesn't show all the lines that come later.

Is there a way to have the systemctl to show all the data as it comes along? Or is there another program that can give me realtime status of dameon services?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOKym.png)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! (But if you know a better method please post).

I used `journalctl -u eprotection -f` and that gives me realtime information so if new events come in, it will show in the websocket:

```
@sock.route('/eprotectview')
def eprotectview(ws):
    data = ws.receive()
    with subprocess.Popen(['journalctl -u eprotection -f'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,bufsize=1,universal_newlines=True) as process:
            for line in process.stdout:
                line = line.rstrip()
                print(line)
                try:
                    ws.send(line+ "\n")
                except:
                    pass
```